# SQL Server : multiple foreign keys from first table linking to the primary key of second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `itemrequest_table` and `item_table`. Four columns of `itemrequest_table` (`item1, item2, item3, item4`) are connected to `item_no` of `item_table`.

I'm trying to write a query to display the item names of item_nos under the column of item1, item2, item3, item4.

But how can I display the item names it? And is it possible to query that?

My tables:

[image]

Comment: Do you always have exactly four items in each request? This looks suspiciously like a typical case of bad table design...

Comment: No sir, item2-item4 are optional, nullable. Ok, i'll fix my table. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do **four** joins between the two tables - one for each item:

```
SELECT
   Item1 = i1.item_name,    
   Item2 = i2.item_name,
   Item3 = i3.item_name,
   Item4 = i4.item_name
FROM
   itemrequest_table ir
INNER JOIN
   item_table i1 ON ir.item1 = i1.item_no
INNER JOIN
   item_table i2 ON ir.item2 = i2.item_no
INNER JOI
   item_table i3 ON ir.item3 = i3.item_no
INNER JOIN
   item_table i4 ON ir.item4 = i4.item_no
```

But this is really a bad design - it smells of first-normal form violation (*repeating columns*). What you **really** should do is just have a relationship between `itemrequest_table` and the `item_table` that allows for any number of connections, if needed (a regular, normal m:n relationship)

Comment: Ok sir, noted. I'll fix my table. Thanks for the help sir

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform four joins:

```
SELECT    ir.request_no, 
          t1.item_name, t2.item_name, t3.item_name, t4.item_name
FROM      itemrequest_table ir
LEFT JOIN item_table t1 ON ir.item1 = t1.item_no
LEFT JOIN item_table t2 ON ir.item2 = t2.item_no
LEFT JOIN item_table t3 ON ir.item3 = t3.item_no
LEFT JOIN item_table t4 ON ir.item4 = t4.item_no
```

EDIT:
As per the comments, these items are optional, so a `left join` should be used instead of a `join`.